# WPF TextBox Databinding woes >:-(

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

What should be one of the most simpliest form of databinding, is now causing me great amounts of grief. In my XAML, I have something as such:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Speed}" />
```

Then in my matching .cs file, I have a property as such:

```
public int Speed { get; set; }
```

But they aren't binding in harmony and I don't understand why. >:-(  Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks in advance! :-D

Comment: In Silverlight, you can only bind to a DependencyProperty. My hunch is that is true in WPF too.

Comment: :( in this codeproject he does something very similiar http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx and a few other examples as well. I haven't tried running their samples, so I don't now for sure if it works or not :(

Comment: @Matt - that's not true in either case. The Target (Text here) needs to be a DP, but the Source can be any CLR property.

Comment: Duh, sorry, my bad. I got them backwards. Disregard my comment please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source for binding by default is the `DataSource` of the control or first ancestor that have a one set. Since the control `DataSource` is probably not the control itself the binding fails.

It can be solved by giving a name to the UserControl (or Window...) and setting the binding with `ElementName`.

For example:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Name="myWindow">
   <Grid>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Speed, ElementName=myWindow}" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: :-O you're my hero! thanks! :D that did it. :-) (7 minutes and I can accept this :-) )

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor in your .cs file try this:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```